# How to group set of time under distinct date from csv file

Tags: python, regex

hi i have just gotten a set of time and date data from csv file using regex:

```
datePattern = re.compile(r"(\d+/\d+/\d+\s+\d+:\d+)")
for i, line in enumerate(open('sample_data.csv')):
    for match in re.finditer(datePattern, line):
        date.append(match.groups());
```

the output is [('30/06/2016 08:30',), ('20/07/2016 09:30',), 
('30/06/2016 07:30',)

How do i turn it into useful information such as listing all the time under the same date such as maybe  [('30/06/2016 08:30',07.30),]

Comment: give us some sample input format and desired output format

Comment: Consider using the built-in [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module for parsing csv, rather than reinventing the wheel.

Comment: i have updated my question with elaboration. can you give me more idea on how i should use built in csv module to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
r"(\d+/\d+/\d+)\s+(\d+:\d+)"
```

[Python code](https://repl.it/DrqS/2) follows, I have used dictionary of lists for such grouping

```
import re

datePattern = re.compile(r"(\d+/\d+/\d+)\s+(\d+:\d+)")  
dateDict =dict()    

for i, line in enumerate(open('sample_data.csv')):
    for match in re.finditer(datePattern,line):
        if match.group(1) in dateDict:
            dateDict[match.group(1)].append(match.group(2))
        else:
            dateDict[match.group(1)] = [match.group(2),]        
print(dateDict)
```

It will output as follows:

```
{'10/10/1990': ['12:20', '11:20'], '10/10/1991': ['16:20', '16:20']}

Tested with python 3+
```

Comment: any idea on how to sort the dates in the dict? such that 1/7/2016 will come before 26/6/2016